# datetime type in Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I have a field in my database (MYSQL) with datetime type (with this format 2011-05-18 16:29:31), I dont know this type! because I Have to convert a String to this type.
I have found java.sql.Date and java.sql.Timestamp and not datetime!

Comment: why do you think that java.sql.* library and MYSQL should have datatypes with same names

Comment: I don't know I have assumed that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

mysql `datetime` maps to a `java.sql.Timestamp` - they are both a "date plus a time"

To convert a String to a Date, use this code:

```
java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2011-05-18 16:29:31");
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Comment: I have convert my date to the format I want but as a String Know I want to convert it to java.util.Timestamp  how could I do that?                                                 DateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateString=out.format(date1);

Comment: Important: Because Timestamp starts from 1970-01-01 it is not an exact matching type for DATETIME. If this is a case for your, for example if you are keeping birth dates at that column, then you'll not be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a date to a timestamp, do the following:

```
    Date now = new Date();
    Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(now.getTime());
```

consult the [javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) for more information

Comment: Important: Because Timestamp starts from 1970-01-01 it is not an exact matching type for DATETIME. If this is a case for your, for example if you are keeping birth dates at that column, then you'll not be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        c.setTime(format.parse("2013-12-10 05:15:00"));
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+"h"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+" Date "+c.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

Something wrong when use java.util.Date, but when i use calendar it work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse("2020-04-21 00:00:00");
java.sql.Timestamp GDDatetimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

step 1 -> make two model claases one class containing date of String type and other class containing date of Timestamp step 2 -> initialise a variable of Date type and convert String date type object into Date and format using SimpleFormat to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" step 3 -> initailise java.sql.Timestamp type variable into Date type variable.getTime() step 4 -> set java.sql.Timestamp type variable into the class containing Timestamp model class object step 5 -> while sending to dao layer make sure jdbctype for date parameter is DATE type

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: purpose is to convert date to timestamp format while saving. I had a model class where TestDate is String Type and I convert String to TimeStamp . how to convert String  to TimeStamp?? so I have object which has TestDate of String Type and I only need a variable of Date Type so I convert String TestDate to Date field by Date testdate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(entity.TestDate()); and then date to timestamp by java.sql.Timestamp Datetimestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(testdate .getTime());

Comment: Please add all explanation **to your answer**

Comment: step 1 -> make two model claases one class containing date of String type and other class containing date of Timestamp
step 2 -> initialise a variable of Date type and convert String date type object into Date and format using SimpleFormat to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
step 3 -> initailise java.sql.Timestamp type variable into Date type variable.getTime()
step 4 -> set java.sql.Timestamp type variable into the class containing Timestamp model class object
step 5 -> while sending to dao layer make sure jdbctype for date parameter is DATE type

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it - **don't use the comment section for this**

Comment: Important: Because Timestamp starts from 1970-01-01 it is not an exact matching type for DATETIME. If this is a case for your, for example if you are keeping birth dates at that column, then you'll not be able to use it.